# Silverlight Access to path is denied

Tags: c#, silverlight, system.io.file

My code reads a text file line by line, it has no compile errors, however when i test it, it shows this: "Access to Path is Denied"

Code:` public void EA()
        {

```
        var lines = File.ReadLines("Status.txt").Skip(81).Take(24).ToList(); //Read txt file line by line
        int timeout = 0;
        int success = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) //for cicle for each line in txt 
        {


            if (lines[i] == "okay")
            {
                success++; //count for how many okay in txt

            }

            else if (lines[i] == "fail")
            {
                timeout++; //count for how many fail in txt
            }
        }
        if (timeout < 1)
        {
            BitmapImage verde = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SilverLightTest;component/Estados/Verde.png", UriKind.Relative));
            eaMafra.Source = verde;

        }

        else
        {
            BitmapImage vermelho = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SilverLightTest;component/Estados/Vermelho.png", UriKind.Relative));
            eaMafra.Source = vermelho;
        }

        if (timeout == 0) //if none, everything is ok
        {
            eaQuantos.Text = "ok";
        }

        else //if any show how many timeouts
        {
            eaQuantos.Text = timeout.ToString();
        }
    }`
```

The Details of the error:

> {System.Security.SecurityException: File operation not permitted. Access to path 'Status.txt' is denied.
>      at System.IO.FileSecurityState.EnsureState()
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
>      at System.IO.File.ReadLines(String path)

I have tried to share the "txt" folder to "everyone" (modify and read) but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Try to change security of  containing folder your txt file for get right access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: We would really need to see your code. By default, a Silverlight app running in a browser is not allowed to read local files, unless a user selects one using the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to format the error message as code, i.e. indent every line with four spaces?

Comment: I updated the question with code now, thanks for the replies

Comment: When  run the application out of the browser, it runs fine. Is it even possible to run an application that reads local files via browser?